# How to write this code in async/callbacks in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am trying to perform SQL queries based on the callback results in if conditions but I am unable to write the code. So can somebody please provide some information how to do this with async/callback methods?

```
app.get('/resell-property', function(req, res) {
    var data = {}
    data.unit_price_id = 1;
    function callback(error, result) {
        if (result.count == 0) {
            return hp_property_sell_request.create(data)
        } else if (result.count > 0) {
            return hp_unit_price.findAll({
                where: {
                    unit_price_id: data.unit_price_id,
                    hp_property_id: data.property_id,
                    hp_unit_details_id: data.unit_details_id
                }
            })
        }
    }


    hp_property_sell_request.findAndCountAll({
        where: {
            unit_price_id: data.unit_price_id
        }
    }).then(function (result) {
        if (result) {
            callback(null, result);
        }
    });    
});
```

How can I write the callbacks for this?

```
hp_property_sell_request.create(data) ,hp_unit_price.findAll({
    where: {
        unit_price_id: data.unit_price_id,
        hp_property_id: data.property_id,
        hp_unit_details_id: data.unit_details_id
    }
})
```

After returning the result I want to handle callbacks and perform this query:

```
if (result.request_id) {
    return hp_unit_price.findAll({
        where: {
            unit_price_id:result.unit_price_id,
            hp_property_id:result.property_id,
            hp_unit_details_id:result.unit_details_id
        }
    }).then(function(result) {
        if (result.is_resale_unit==0 && result.sold_out==0) {
            return Sequelize.query('UPDATE hp_unit_price SET resale_unit_status=1 WHERE hp_unit_details_id='+result.unit_details_id+' and  hp_property_id='+result.property_id)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is for answering questions, not providing advice. Please take some time to revise your answer and ask something specific. Also, please fix your code's indentation, it's very hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too vague to answer precisely. I am assuming you need to call two methods and the latter should be called after the first method is completed and you need the results from the first method available in second methods.

Now, to the solution

Please note that callback and promise are very different approaches. It is very wise to stick with only one and not to mix callbacks and promises.
For your requirement, I highly recommend promises to avoid 
[callback hell.](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/node-js-callback-hell-promises-generators/)

Using callbacks, the solution looks something like

```
app.get('/resell-property', function(req, res) {
method1(req.body.id,function(err,result){
    return method2(result);
})
function method1(input1,callback(err,result)){
    try{
        var result=st.execute("query");
        return callback(null,result)
    }catch(error){
        return callback(error,null);
    }
}
function method2(input2){
    return input2;
}
})
```